# What is the word for a university student who has a job at university?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I have to produce a copy of my CV in English and I don't know how to properly describe the position.

When I was a Master student, I was employed by a professor at our department, for whom I did some software development, some research, and anything the researchers didn't want to do by themselves (yes I had to clean the coffee machine). I think that such positions are regulated by law (at least they are here) and have a special, generally recognized name. Only I don't know that name in English.

If there are regional differences, I will need an American English variant.

Comment: *Busy*? *Stressed*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for *[research assistant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_assistant)*. If you also did teaching, you were (also) a *[teaching assistant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_assistant)*.

Comment: I am not sure this is exactly what I am looking for, as I've only ever come across "research assistant" as a term for full-time employed graduate students, and I was part-time only. It is also somewhat unusual that I did research too, most students in this position get only non-creative tasks unrelated to research.

Comment: @rumtscho: Well perhaps it depends on the institution, I am not sure. Perhaps someone else can give you a better label. But you mentioned "full-time employed graduate students": how can a student be employed full time? When does he find the time to study? This would only be possible if his Master's programme consisted in being a research assistant. If you're not enrolled in a Master's programme and you are employed full time to assist a principal researcher at a university, you might be a *research associate*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_associate

Comment: +1 in the US and Canada its `RA` ("Research Assistant").  If you did any research at all then you were an `RA`.  If you lead tutorials/classes or marked assignments, then you were a `TA` ("teaching assistant")

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Cerberus that RA or TA are the terms most often used at universities for the position described. The only other word I can offer is *intern*. That's certainly someone who would clean out coffee pots and the like.

Comment: I would not say "intern" -- intern usually denotes an _out of school_ educational experience at some business or corporation

Answer (score 1):

Intern sounds like a fair term

Answer (score 1):

I would use the term *student assistant*. Research and Teaching Assistants are usually paid more and have goodies like tuition stipend, whereas student assistants get paid considerably less. I've done all three roles :)